# Spring LDAP - batch lookup full DNs

Tags: ldap, spring-ldap

I am using spring-ldap, and I have a situation where I have to look up a bunch of full DNs from an AD server. There is a good amount of latency on the way to the AD server, so if i just do N lookups sequentially:

```
 LdapTemplate.findByDn(dn,MyClass);
```

it tends to be rather slow, despite not being a very expensive operation itself. If I had the GUIDs, for example, I could simply do batches or OR conditions:

```
 (|(objectGUID=A)(objectGUID=B)(objectGUID=C))
```

but I can't find a way to do the same for full DNs. Does this even exist? I would like to avoid running N queries in parallel if I can ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is an Active Directory domain, search for the fully qualified DNs in the distinguishedName attribute:

```
(|(distinguishedName=CN=Lisa,OU=ResourceUsers,DC=example,DC=com)(distinguishedName=CN=Scott,OU=ResourceUsers,DC=example,DC=com)(distinguishedName=CN=Anya,OU=ResourceUsers,DC=example,DC=com))
```

Or, if possible, have all valid users added to a group and search for individuals who are a member of the group (this avoids having to adjust your LDAP query every time a user is added/removed) -- add an account to the group and they'll show up in your query, remove someone from the group and they'll disappear from the result set.

```
(&(memberOf=cn=MyGroupName,ou=OUForGroups,dc=example,dc=com))
```

Comment: hi lisa. awesome, thank you! i tried "dn=...", assuming that in AD, "dn" is an alias ... but it's not. it does work with an OR filter for distringuishedName.